# Matplotlib pyplot.title(string) returns error

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

When I call `pyplot.title('some string')` it throws the exception, `'str' object is not callable'`.
I copied the following from the matplotlib online documentation:

```
mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)

# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 50, normed=1, facecolor='g', alpha=0.75)


plt.xlabel('Smarts')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.title('Histogram of IQ')
plt.text(60, .025, r'$\mu=100,\ \sigma=15$')
plt.axis([40, 160, 0, 0.03])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

and get

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-158-40fe7a831b06> in <module>()
      8 plt.xlabel('Smarts')
      9 plt.ylabel('Probability')
---> 10 plt.title('Histogram of IQ')
     11 plt.text(60, .025, r'$\mu=100,\ \sigma=15$')
     12 plt.axis([40, 160, 0, 0.03])

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

`pyplot.suptitle()` works OK

I'm using python 2.7.5 and the latest release of matplotlib on an iMac with an I7 processor OSX 10.8 and 8 gig ram and ipython notebook.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: It works for me on OSX 10.8.5 with Python 2.7.5 and matplotlib 1.3.0. How did you install ipython and matplotlib? Is the above code the only code you evoke? Do you run `ipython notebook --pylab` or how do you initialize it?

Comment: I also can not re-produce this.  Do you have a `plt.title = 'blah'` someplace in your code above this?

Comment: I reinstalled matplotlib (pip uninstall then pip install) and all is OK. Before this ?plt.title told me that plt.title was a string. Now it confirms that plt.title is a function.  Not sure I undetstand all of it but it's working. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 130):

It happened to me because I tried to do `plot.title = "Some string"` so that rewrote the `title()` method. That's the exact reason why it happens :) .
As others have said you just need to restart the kernel, no need to reinstall.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer here... having rewritten the 'title' is the root cause to the probem

Comment: I accidentally assigned the title method to a string and that caused this issue. After restarted the kernel it worked.

Comment: Thank you! I think I made the same mistake, and restarting the kernel solved my problem also.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem. The code was fine, but in the interpreter, I had previoulsy used incorrect xlabel() calls.
re-starting the interpreter (close and reopen it) was enough for me, no need to reinstall all python/matplotlib !

Comment: Same problem - I'm working in Jupyter and once I restarted the kernel I was all set.

Answer (score 14):

I've had this happen when I've previously accidentally plt.title = ''

After that that function is no longer a function.
Restarting python kernel or re-importing plt library can fix it.

Not re-installing. Re-IMPORTING.

Comment: No kidding. If you previously accidentally assign a string to function it becomes a string??

Answer (score 11):

Try to reload matplotlib by running the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from importlib import reload
plt=reload(plt)
```

**Good Luck**

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem where I wrote `plt.title = "This is a sample plot"` instead of `plt.title("This is a sample plot")`. I was getting the error:

> typeerror 'str' object is not callable

Restarting the Spyder IDE fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

No need to Reinstall any libraries. To overcome the issue, you can just restart the Jupyter kernel. This happens when you set plt.title = 'something'. It overrides the PyPlot functions and make them inaccessible. Restarting the kernel will help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Without restarting, I've found that changing to a `.set_title()` method following my plotting method has resulted in a successful pass without an error.

Answer (score 2):

1. Restart your kernel
2. ```
    plt.suptitle("title name")
   ```
3. ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from importlib import reload
   plt=reload(plt)
   ```

Comment: the code is not well organized

Comment: Reloading worked great! But I didn't need to restart the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem olben1, using ipython, anaconda and the --pylab flag. Reinstalled and it worked. Fwiw, using an anaconda env makes the uninstall/reinstall easier..

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem after removing the line

```
%matplotlib inline
```

and Restarting the notebook again solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

plt.title('xyz') :'str' object is not callable.

just give a restart of your terminal/ide. That ll fix the issue .

Answer (score -1):

Just restart the kernel. It works. Worked for me.

Comment: At least three other answers already mention this. Please don't repeat answers.