# Error plot str' object is not callable python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

I am 
    trying to  create a plot with titles but getting this error I am using spyder 3.7

Error:

```
   plt.title("Year vs Population in Bulgaria")

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

years = [1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987]
total_populations = [8939007, 8954518, 8960387, 8956741, 8943721]

plt.plot(years, total_populations)
plt.title("Year vs Population in Bulgaria")
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Total Population")
plt.show()
```

It should show the title. I have removed and use it other options but I still have issues I cant figure out

Comment: It works well on my computer with your code.

Comment: Is this your entire code? Could you check if there are any other variables named `plt` that might be getting called instead?

Comment: What does `print(plt)` return?

Comment: it doesnt return anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also tested your code, and it ran without any issues. This might be a problem solved by a good old restart, like Tianmin Lyu said.

Also, in case you changed something in your system recently after which this behavior started, maybe try to revert back to that setup on which you know it worked.

Comment: Thank you for testing my code I havent changed anything I just did the installation and I keep getting that error maybe something is missing?

Comment: Persoanlly, I do not have any experience with Spyder. In case you haven’t already, can you try and run the script with ”python path/to/file.py” in a terminal?

Answer (score 2):

`plt.title="Your title"` works fine

Instead of `plt.title("Your title")`

Answer (score 0):

Yout code works fine on my Jupyter Notebook. And I've found a similar question, hope it works

[Matplotlib pyplot.title(string) returns error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442060/matplotlib-pyplot-titlestring-returns-error)

Comment: Even though this question has not been given a best answer, I think one piece of advice can be tried: restart the kernel